# BeginTransaction with IsolationLevel in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, isolation-level

I'm trying to rewrite old library to use EntityFramework Core and I can't figure out how to begin transaction with specific isolation level.

Previously I was able to do something like this:

```
DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
```

What is alternative implementation in the EntityFramework Core?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The EF Core code is exactly the same.

```
DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
```

The only difference is that in EF Core the [method with isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.begintransaction?view=efcore-2.1) (as many others) is an *extension* method, defined in [RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions?view=efcore-2.1) class, and importantly, located in [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) assembly.

So if you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` and don't see it, add reference to the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll` assembly / package.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Ivan Stoev's answer, it is also important to use `System.Data.IsolationLevel` and not `System.Transactions.IsolationLevel` when calling `BeginTransaction` method.