# Using context.Database.BeginTransaction() not allowing to query to the database until Commit

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For a transaction rollback I use `using (var dbTran = context.Database.BeginTransaction())`. Before the `dbTran.Commit()` I have a LinQ query to get some data.. However, the  `LinQ query` fails. I guess its because of the `BeginTransaction` method which is not allowing to query to the database. Is my assumption correct and is there a way around to get this done.

Comment: This question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208184/begintransaction-with-isolationlevel-in-ef-core

Comment: What does “The Linq query fails” mean? Does it return an empty list? Does it throw an exception? If yes, provide the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: i tried as suggested by @Klaus and modified the code to using `(var dbTran = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Read.Uncommited))` still i get an exception as ` InnerException {"Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}`
I am getting this exception on query for the newly made transaction which is yet uncommitted. Is there a way to read even the uncommitted transaction.

Comment: @ckuri To explain the above error, the application allows user to create associates. On creation of an associate there are 4 transactions happening, 2 for saving the details in 2 associate tables and other 2 for updating the Audit table for the 2 entries. Here I am using `BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Read.Uncommited))` for the transactions to rollback to cater unprecedented scenarios. After saving an entry in the associate table I am querying for the record in the associate table where it gives me the above exception even though I am using `Read.Uncommited`